# Neural Network architecture to learn function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I'm designing a neural network to learn a function of the form:

```
P = (x^2 * y)/z
```

I'm using the keras library to build the neural net with:

```
def custom_activation(x):
    return keras.backend.square(x)

def custom_activation2(x):
    return keras.backend.pow(x,-1)

get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(custom_activation)})
get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation2': Activation(custom_activation2)})

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = custom_activation))
```

[image]

Using this architecture I'm able to learn a function as shown in the blue line of the image. It seems that using `custom_activation`, I'm able to incorporate `x^2` part of the equation.

How do I change my architecture to incorporate the `y` and the `z` part of the equation?

I do have the `custom_activation2`, but not sure how to add it in my architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misconception here. If you already now that your function has the form `x^2*y/z`, then you do not need to use a neural network to learn this function. Especially, you do not have to invent new activation functions which resemble your ground truth function. A neural network is often considered as a "universal approximator", see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem). Loosely speaking that means that a sufficiently large feed forward network can approximate any continuous function.

So, if you already now that your function looks like `f(x,y,z)=x^2*y/z` and you only look for some parameters in your function to fit it to your data, then have a look at nonlinear regression, [for example with scipy](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html).

If you insist on using a neural network, then leave it to the network to find the right parameters use standard activation functions and topologies. This is often a good start and refinements can be done later.

To see that this works, look at this example code, where a simple feed forward network is trained. Notice that I did not spend much time on the architecture so there is plenty of room for improving this.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import losses
from keras import regularizers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gen_data(batch_size=100):
    while True:
        X = np.zeros((batch_size, 3))
        x1 = np.random.random(batch_size) * 10 + 1
        x2 = np.random.random(batch_size) * 10 + 1
        x3 = np.random.random(batch_size) * 10 + 1
        y = x1 * x1 * x2 / x3
        X[:, 0] = x1
        X[:, 1] = x2
        X[:, 2] = x3
        yield X, y


def plot_loss(history):
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()


def fit_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=3, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation=None))
    model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss=losses.mean_squared_error)
    history = model.fit_generator(gen_data(), steps_per_epoch=200, epochs=15, validation_data=gen_data(),
                                  validation_steps=200)
    return history


history = fit_model()
plot_loss(history)
```

This results in a loss curve that looks like this:
[image]